# How to sort the index of a dataframe based on the numerical part?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
              Max
step1   2.001953125
step19  86.669921875
step2   2.001953125
step24  2.24609375
step25  2.001953125
step26  2.001953125
step27  2.001953125
step5   46.97265625
```

The column containing the `step`s is the index and I want to sort it to be as follows:

```
            Max
step1   2.001953125
step2   2.001953125
step5   46.97265625
step19  86.669921875
step24  2.24609375
step25  2.001953125
step26  2.001953125
step27  2.001953125
```

I tried doing:

```
steps_max.sort_index(inplace = True)
```

but it doesn't work.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:
Extract only numbers using [`series.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and `\d+` for extracting only numeric values and then `sort_values()`, finnaly use that index in [`df.reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to reindex the dataframe.

> \d  :  Any numeric digit from 0 to 9.

```
i=df.index.to_series().str.extract('(\d+)',expand=False).astype(float).sort_values().index
df.reindex(i)
```

---

```
              Max
step1    2.001953
step2    2.001953
step5   46.972656
step19  86.669922
step24   2.246094
step25   2.001953
step26   2.001953
step27   2.001953
```

Another method would be using [`natsort`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/):

```
import natsort as ns
df.reindex(ns.natsorted(df.index))
#df.reindex(sorted(ns.natsorted(df.index), key=lambda x: not x.isdigit()))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. it works. Can you please explain me how it works and what is the `'(\d+)'` part?

Comment: @Junkrat added explanation.